# Boys and girls ending up in same pair

Tags: combinatorics

100 boys and 100 girls are randomly assigned into 100 pairs. What are some ways to calculate how many groups get 2 girls?

I can calculate this using a computer program in Python, that I know, how do I think about it mathematically, that I want to learn.

```
# cook your code here
import random
list=[]
girls=[]
boys=[]
duplicate = 0

for i in range(200):

          r=random.randint(1,100)
          if list.count(r) < 2: 
              list.append(r)
              if i % 2 == 0:
                  girls.append(r)
                  if girls.count(r) == 2: 
                      duplicate += 1
              else:
                  boys.append(r)

          else:
              i -= 1


print(duplicate)
```

Comment: As the assignment is random, there won't be a fixed number of such groups. Do you want the expected number?

Comment: how to calculate what the script does using basic math principles

Comment: What are you looking for? The code gives a random pairing and tells you how many girls. Do you want this number on average? The variance? The distribution?

Comment: how to think about it mathematically

Comment: (so that I do not have to write a program to calculate it)

Comment: One way that allows you to get the expectation easy is to define the random variable $X_i$ as the event that the $i$th pair is girl-girl.  The number of girl-girl pairs is then $\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$.  The expectation is then $\sum_i\Pr[X_i=1]$.  The probability the first person in the $i$th pair is a girl is $1/2$.  The probability the second is as well is $\frac{n-1}{2n-1}$.  Thus the expectation is $n\frac{1}{2}\frac{n-1}{2n-1}\approx \frac{n}{4}$.  Does this help?